# Oracle.DataAccess.Client not seeing tables but same query in Toad does

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

If I write a simple query like "SELECT * FROM r56.Pets;" in Toad results are returned.  If I execute the same query, using the same login in my c# application using Oracle.DataAccess.Client, I get the error "ORA-00942 table of view does not exist"

The Connection that works in toad is 11g.

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

string ConnectionString = "UserId=username;Password=password;Data Source=dbname.domain.com;";


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = DbTools.GetConnectionString("oracle");
                conn.Open();

                OracleDataAdapter oraAdapt = new OracleDataAdapter(qry, conn);
                oraAdapt.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                conn.Close();
                return null;
            }

base    {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection} System.Data.Common.DbConnection {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection}
    ConnectionString    "User Id=username;Data Source=dbname.domain.com;"   string
    ConnectionTimeout   15  int
    ConnectionType  Oracle  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionType
    Database    ""  string
    DatabaseDomainName  "domain.com"    string
    DatabaseName    "dbname"    string
    DataSource  "dbname.domain.com" string
    HostName    "host"  string
    InstanceName    "dbname"    string
    LogicalTransactionId    null    byte[]
    OracleLogicalTransaction    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleLogicalTransaction
    ServerVersion   "11.2.0.4.0"    string
    ServiceName "sys$users" string
    State   Open    System.Data.ConnectionState
    StatementCacheSize  30  int
```

Comment: check the runtime values of `conn.ConnectionString` and `qry` in a debugger. Do they match with what you use in Toad? When you connect to a particular schema, you may omit the schema name in the query.

Comment: It seems the same to me.  I can connect a similar database and query fine just not in this schema.  I had to be granted access to see the tables in Toad the other day but the tables seem to not be visible to the C# application even though it is using the same login I use in Toad.

Yes, the query is the same.

Comment: It must have something to do with the schema containing the table I need access too.  I used a different schema on the same database and was able to query successfully.

Comment: If I use a shema name in my query it will always fail in the c# app.  If I query without a schema name for the table I need "r65" schema, it is not found.  So frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding more info to my FROM clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE@Database.domain.COM
```